# Split by regex yield "undefined"

Tags: javascript, regex

[*I have a code which*](http://jsbin.com/uwemeh/5/edit) extract query string parameters :

So ( for example) if the window url is :

`....&a=1&.....`

--The code first using `split` on `&` and then do split on the `=`

however , sometimes we use base64 values  , which can have extra finals `='s` (padding).

[And here is where my code is messed up.](http://jsbin.com/uwemeh/6/edit)

the result is `N4JOJ7yZTi5urACYrKW5QQ` and it should be `N4JOJ7yZTi5urACYrKW5QQ==`

So I enhance my regex to :

**search** `=` such that **after** it **->** ( `there is no end` **OR** `there is no [=]`)

`'a=N4JOJ7yZTi5urACYrKW5QQ=='.split(/\=(?!($|=))/)`

*it does work.* ( *you can run it on console*)

but the result is `["a", undefined, "N4JOJ7yZTi5urACYrKW5QQ=="]`

- Why am I getting  undefined
- How can i cure my regex for yielding only `["a", "N4JOJ7yZTi5urACYrKW5QQ=="]`

*p.s.
I know i can replace all the finals `=`'s to something temporary and then  replace it back
but this tag is tagged as regex. So im looking a way to fix my regex.*

Comment: You can also use `.filter(function(n){ return n; })` to remove empty matches.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens because you have additional match `($|=)`. You can exclude it from matching with `?:`:

```
"a=N4JOJ7yZTi5urACYrKW5QQ==".split(/=(?!(?:$|=))/);
```

However, you can always *flatten* that match and remove extra block:

```
"a=N4JOJ7yZTi5urACYrKW5QQ==".split(/=(?!$|=)/);
```

Comment: Thanks Does `?:`  is uncaptured group ?

Comment: What do you mean by _you have additional match_ ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir Any parentheses `()` used add to your regex a new match. To exclude it from the remembered matches, `(?:)` is used. Refer to: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-non-capturing-parentheses.

Comment: Thanks that 's what i thought ( uncaptured group.) can you please explain what do you mean by : _This happens because you have additional match_ ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir See, in your regex `/\=(?!($|=))/` you have `$|=` wrapped in *capturing parentheses*, which makes your code to remember a new *additional* match. This match adds a new *segment* for `split`, that results in `undefined`.

Comment: Does `?!$|=` means `?!$ or =` or `$ or =`  ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir In the latter case?

Comment: @RoyiNamir This means `$` or `=`.

Answer (score 5):

The url needs to be encoded

```
'a=N4JOJ7yZTi5urACYrKW5QQ=='
```

should be

```
'a=N4JOJ7yZTi5urACYrKW5QQ%3D%3D'
```

Look into `encodeURIComponent()`

And if you want to use a reg expression to get the key from the value

```
> "abc=fooo".match(/([^=]+)=?(.*)?/);
  ["abc=fooo", "abc", "fooo"]
```

Answer (score 1):

why must you use split?  a regex **match** with two captures, like `/^(.+)=(.+)$/` would seem more obvious.

Comment: well it is possible for it not to have a value which this would miss.